# Getting content excerpt Wikipedia with JSON & PHP

Tags: php, json, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I have tried many different variations here - how can I get the content summary from this: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=stack_overflow&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0c

Here's what I have so far:

```
$wiki_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=stack_overflow&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0c.json";
$json = file_get_contents($wiki_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

I know I need to do something like echo `$data[0]->query` but am unable to get it to do anything.

Comment: Since you set the second argument of `json_decode` to true, you are working with an array only. You may use `$data['query'][...]` freely.

Answer (score 2):

```
$wiki_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=stack_overflow&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0c.json";
$json = file_get_contents($wiki_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach ($data['query']['pages'] as $page) {
    print_r($page['revisions'][0]['*']);
}
```

Comment: Ps. Depending on what you want to do with the content, you might also want to [consider](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12337968/411022) using [prop=extracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&titles=stack_overflow&prop=extracts&exchars=1000) instead.